# How to import canoe System environment and symbols and build vTeststudio through script

Tags: c#, capl, canoe

I have a vTeststudio project mapped to a canoe configuration. So every time the canoe configuration changes I need to automatically do the Import Canoe System Environment and Symbols  and Build the vTeststudio project.

Is there any API or script which would support Import Canoe System Environment and Symbols and build the Vteststudio project?

I have gone through the help documents of vTeststudio but could not get any information on this. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: It is not a direct solution, and I am not 100% it will work but I think it worth a try.  
Little explenation: when you import canoe configuration, the vTestStudio saves references to some files (e.g. *.cdd, *.dbc, etc). So if any of these files changes, the vTestStudio namespaces are instantly updated as well (no need for making another import).  
You might try to export all system and environment variables to *.dbc and *.sysvar external files (and attach them in CANoe simulation). When you make first import in vTestStudio, it will create links to these files (not sure about *.sysvar)

Comment: are you updating system variables every time or what are you changing every time?

Comment: Yeah, I am making an update in vTESTStudio everytime that I make some major changes in Vector CANoe (changing database I am using - e.g. switching to other version of *.cdd file, changing system/environment variables etc.).

Answer (score 1):

In Home ribbon there is configuration. If you go to configuration >> System environment>>Surce of description file, there is a checkbox for "Configure in vTESTstudio or import from CANoe" check this box so the CANoe system environment and symbols get imported here and configured. All the next builds will be configured identical. Will get auto configured in vTESTstudio if you change the config. in CANoe. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution here is this:
Instead of creating a script and then running it to link the files between CANoe and vTestStudio, you can just click the Import button in the project configuration in vTestStudio by having the CANoe configuration open.